# How to use a shell script to stop CLI if one arg matches

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Basically, I'm trying to disable a CLI's "delete" function in order to prevent myself (and others) from inadvertently deleting our environments. I want to basically intercept `amplify delete` (including subsequent arguments) and echo something like `you are not supposed to do this.`

```
 amplify() {
   local -a args=( )
   for arg; do
     # if arg == delete
     echo "This command is disabled."
   done
 }
```

The catch is that I still want the rest of the CLI arguments to work. So if I type in `amplify status`, that should run. Just not `amplify delete` or `amplify delete --arg2 --arg3 --etc`

Comment: `amplify() {  if echo "$@" |grep -qw delete ;then echo 'this command is disabled' ;return 1 ;fi }` untested, but should work if you save this in your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a wrapper over the `amplify()` function like you had and check if the argument is set to `delete`

```
amplify() {
   [ "$1" = "delete" ] && { >&2 printf '%s\n' "This command is disabled."; return; }
   command amplify "$@"
}
```

The `command` before `amplify` ensures this time, the binary is searched int the `PATH` variable for execution.